# what does した mean?

Tags: meaning, definitions

What does した mean? Google translate says it means "did", but once again i'm not convinced. Thanks!

Comment: context........

Comment: Context is vital in Japanese. Many things can have loads of different meanings and it's impossible to tell what the meaning is without the context. した could mean 'tongue', 'under' etc. Most likely you saw it as the past tense of する. What does する mean? Again, it depends on the context. It is better to post full sentences and explain the problem you are having, but even full sentences can sometimes be ambiguous without further context.

Answer (score 1):

It means "I did / have done that thing.".

Comment: Thank you! I will add context in the future, my apologies.